# How do I lock the entire dependency tree with JSPM?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, jspm, lockfile

I am working on a project with a number of frontend dependencies. The project uses both NPM and JSPM to manage these dependencies.

According to the [jspm documentation:](https://jspm.org/docs/0.16/installing-packages.html)

> All install ranges are saved in the package.json file, with the exact version solution saved into config.js. Both of these files should be checked into version control.
>
> To reproduce an install of the package.json to the exact version ranges in the config.js file, use `jspm install` with no arguments:

However, even with a package.json that has explicit versions set, the presence of a package-lock.json file and the presence of a config.js file (that is supposed to ensure a consistent jspm_packages folder), I still see floating version information shown when running `jspm install` - example:

```
ok   Installed npm:buffer@^5.0.6 (5.1.0)
ok   Installed npm:ieee754@^1.1.4 (1.1.11)
ok   Installed npm:base64-js@^1.0.2 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed core-js as npm:core-js@1.1.4 (1.2.7)
```

Can any frontend gurus tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I assume in your config.js there is information regarding the exact version installed and in logs you might be seeing that npm:buffer@^5.0.6 results in --> (5.1.0)